# Show current locations in MKMapView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, core-location

I'm fairly new to Swift and the following code isn't asking me for location privileges or showing my current location in MKMapView. I have already added NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription to my info.plist but my simulator is still not asking for my permission for location or showing my current loc.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class MapViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
  @IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!
  var locationManager: CLLocationManager!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled())
    {
      locationManager = CLLocationManager()
      locationManager.delegate = self
      locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
      locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
      locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
  }

  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let location = locations.last
    {
      let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
      let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))
      self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
  }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (1) You are using a wrong privacy guy.  (2) Where is your location?  If you are using the iPhone simulator, you need to select your location.

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting authorization when the location services are enabled. The if block would never be executed as the location services are disabled by default. Rather check the authorization status for **authorizationStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined** and then request authorization.